# PayPal Orders API: MISSING_SHIPPING_ADDRESS error when using SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS

Tags: php, paypal

I'm writing WP plugin that adds a paypal button to a page. There is a js file (example from paypal site here):

```
    paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder() {   
                return fetch( dir + '/includes/api/create-paypal-order.php', {           
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  cart: [
                    {
                      sku: "YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT",
                      quantity: "YOUR_PRODUCT_QUANTITY",
                    },
                  ],
                }),
                referrerPolicy: "origin-when-cross-origin" 
              })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((order) => order.id)
              .then((order) => {console.log(order); return order;} );
            },
            onApprove(order) {  
             ...
            },
          }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

And also the php file (create-paypal-order.php):

```
function create_order()
{
    $ch = false;
    $client_id = "Ac9...Fq";    
    $client_secret = "ECn...fH";
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ':' . $client_secret);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);

    $access_token = $json->access_token;
    print_r( $access_token );
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch = false;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": 
            [{    
                "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",    
                "amount": 
                    {        
                    "currency_code": "USD",      
                    "value": "10.00"      
                    }    
                }  
            ], 
        "payment_source": {    
            "paypal": 
                {      
                    "experience_context": 
                    {        
                    "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",        
                    "payment_method_selected": "PAYPAL",        
                    "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC",        
                    "locale": "en-US",        
                    "landing_page": "LOGIN",
                    "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
                    "user_action": "PAY_NOW",       
                    "return_url": "https://example.com/returnUrl",        
                    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancelUrl"      
                    }    
                }  
        }
    }');
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Paypal-Request-Id: 7b92603e-77ed-4896-8e78-5dea2050476a';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_encode($result);
    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
create_order();
```

When i click on the paypal button, it tries to open a modal window with a form, but it immediately disappears.
I looked in the browser dev tools Network tab to observe what the route "/includes/api/create-paypal-order.php" returns when a button is clicked and see error "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY":
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b'/shipping/address","issue":"MISSING_SHIPPING_ADDRESS","description":"The shipping address is required when `shipping_preference=SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS`."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"c41ec50f69e7d","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MISSING_SHIPPING_ADDRESS","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

I am testing this used paypal sandbox. I have make app in paypal sandbox and use Client ID and  Client secret from this site. And my plugin is on localhost(I use XAMPP).

I don't know why this error occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: It tells you `MISSING_SHIPPING_ADDRESS`, `The shipping address is required when shipping_preference=SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS`. The details for `SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS` says "Use the merchant-provided address. The customer cannot change this address on the PayPal site."

Comment: That line isn't required, and if you aren't passing in the shipping address, I'd just remove that line

Comment: Yes, this plugin will be used to sell virtual goods and the address is generally not needed. And in the PayPal modal window, there is the ability to enter an address, but the modal window immediately disappears and I don’t have time to enter something there.

Comment: Thanks! I shange it to NO_SHIPPING and all is working!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress plugins to edit checkout fields and you disable them from a plugin, you have to modify it first for the rest to work, the field needs to be changed from 'required' to 'not required'. Then you just have to remove the check and that's it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Idk what happened but I had some custom changes to the checkout and disabled the plugin that did the checkout edits. Then it started to work. Then i re-enabled the plugin and it still continued working...so Im not sure if it was just something to do with Cache...that got cleared when I disabled the plugin.

It was working while logged in but not while logged out

Answer (score 0):

Set value:

```
"shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING"
```

Source: Paypal API Docs https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Finally found the answer.

If your selling Digital Downloadssss.

Don't forget to Mark "Virtual" Box [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqml8.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).